# Extending the definition of an ultraproduct.

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

I was reading [this](https://dra.american.edu/islandora/object/thesesdissertations%3A445?solr_nav%5Bid%5D=9e53baf24644638883a0&solr_nav%5Bpage%5D=0&solr_nav%5Boffset%5D=0) article which explains proof of compactness theorem using los's theorem.  I read until the definitions given for reduced products, ultraproducts, ultrapower in page 15. Now in page 19 they provided that they extend the definition of ultraproducts over sets and rather define them for structures(They did it for models).

**My question:-**

$(1)$- I didn't understand first of all what an atomic formula is,
I request to give an example if possible. So i was thinking if it's same as equality relation in general.
For example, let $x_1,x_2$ be two variables (All variables are terms). When I say those two variables are same then does it mean that $x_1=x_2$??

Is it correct way to think?

$(2)$- I even didn't understand the definition of ultraproduct they mentioned for structures?
I even request an explanation of it in possibly deep way.

Comment: hi Rahul; I'm assuming you saw the definition of atomic formulas on page 17. given a first-order language $L$, do you know what the "terms" of $L$ and the "relation symbols" of $L$ are?

Comment: Yaa, I know that. But I actually didn't see what does $=$ meant there. I mean that they said $t_1=t_2$, I didn't see what it meant?? . Any example exactly at that point would be so helpful.

Comment: hi Rahul. $=$ means the equality symbol of first-order logic; perhaps you have seen it as $\dot{=}$? if $t_1$ and $t_2$ are terms of $L$, then $t_1=t_2$ is a first-order formula of $L$. for example, in the language $L=\{f\}$ with a single unary function symbol, the formula $f(x)=y$ is an atomic formula for any variables $x$ and $y$. does that make sense as an example?

Comment: @Atticus Stonestrom, oo i got it now. Similarly I would request to explain my second question please.

Comment: great! happy that helped :) ... the second question is rather broader. are you able to identify which parts of the ultraproduct construction are confusing you? (eg is it the definition of the underlying set of the structure, or the realization of it as an $L$-structure?)

Comment: Well, most honestly first of all I don't see what it has to do with notion of ultraproducts with sets. And at the same time I didn't understand how the functions , constants and relations were defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133650/discussion-between-rahul-and-atticus-stonestrom).

Comment: (dear Rahul, I am finishing something up at present but I will try to find the time to address your questions later today.)